# sending data from front end to node.js server

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I am trying to create a simple HTML5 video analytics engine.The data collected from video player(Mouse movement event) is being stored in an array which is then pushed to server using ajax call inside "*onMouseMove(event)*".

Although this approach works I have two questions:

1.)I want to know whether this is right way to send data and

2.)If the player sends large quantity of data, I am getting following error:

XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2f78, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002f78.

```
 function onMouseMove( event ) {
       //object to store data
        var dat ={
            x:null,
            y:null,
            time:null,
        };

         //calculating vector1 here
         //storing the values in temp object
         var curr_time = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
         dat.x = vector1.x;
         dat.y = vector1.y;
         dat.time = curr_time;

          //pushing the data to server
         dataPoints.push(dat);
                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(dataPoints),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    url: 'http://localhost:1337/endpoint',                      
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log('success');
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(dataPoints));
                    }
                });
        }
```

**Node code snippet to handle data**

```
  var data;

  app.post('/endpoint', function(req, res){
  data = req.body;
  console.log(obj);
  });
```

My question regarding node is that this code will work only for single player.How can I modify it to so that it can aggregate the data which  is being sent from multiple players.

Comment: You should throttle and batch the mouse moves. It would seem that you are also sending the entire list of past mouse moves to the server every time the mouse moves, which is unlikely to be what you want. Also, what does this have to do with node? Finally, what do you mean by saying "binding" in your question title?

Comment: Can you reproduce this somewhere like c9.io? Please include information like browser version and node version in your question.

Comment: Edited my question